# How to define a replacement of a specific location in wamp using apache alias directories?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-2

I have a program for file uploading in PHP Codeigniter.
My destination path for file uploading is  **C:/wamp/www/Project1/Uploads**
Now I am trying to replace destination path from web root to local drive without changing PHP program.

> so i added alias on Apache Alias directories

```
Alias C:/wamp/www/Project1/Uploads/ "D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/" 

<Directory "D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all      
</Directory>
```

> My need is

1. whenever PHP program  to check a file exists in /Project1/Uploads it
   will check in local path
2. whenever i am uploading a file it will copy to local path rather
   than /Project1/Uploads

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
<Directory "D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride all
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

note that alias requires the first argument to be a ***url-path***, if you define it as:

```
Alias /Uploads/ "D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/"
```

calling your project from the browser `http://domanin/Uploads` will serve files from `D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/` as apposed to the deafult project's location

i don't think `Alias` will help you solve your problem. i would suggest instead a [symbolic link](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10)

```
mklink /d D:/Prject1Alias/Uploads/ C:/wamp/www/Project1/Uploads/
```